# Is it possible to fan-out an istream to multiple readers?

Tags: c++, c++11, istream

I have an [`std::istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) to work with. Is it possible to somehow pass it on to multiple readers which will potentially seek to and read from different positions?

If not, what if I restrict it to the case of an [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream)?

Comment: I think streams are not copyable. so idea of passing same stream object is not feasible.

Comment: I don't know if range-v3 comes with such functionality, but I imagine it wouldn't be too bad to write a nice range function like that for an `InputRange`. If nothing else, looping through the input lazily and returning a range of output copies ([1,2,3] -> [[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]]), with the number determined by a parameter. Unfortunately, such a straightforward solution is potentially not great for seeking.

Comment: Seeking from multiple places on the same `std::istream` will overwrite the other seeks. If its a file, you could potentially open up multiple `std::ifstream`s for the same file and seek to different locations; the OS may optimize access for you.

Answer (score -1):

You already answered your question.  If it is filestream (ifstream) you get random access (read only; you can set open mode), there should be no problem with multiple threads accessing the same file by opening multiples ifstreams each for one thread. The C++ standard said nothing about thread-safeness about ifstream. For the generic istream (socket, cin), if you use the get() method you will be consuming input stream. I don't see any document for thread-safe of istream.  the peek() method will not consume the input stream but will still change the internal state of the istream. If multiple threads doing seek() on the same istream, the behavior is undefined.  You are not assured of an internal lock by the C++ language. The seek() is basically dereferencing some sort of pointer to an internal buffer.

I would suggest that you have one thread reading the istream into some buffer (constructed objects (the producer), or simple raw memory), then, multiple threads can consume the result (consumer). This is typical consumer/producer synchronization; any multi-threading text book will teach you how to do it.

Comment: The different threads will interfere with each other when they seek, regardless of the stream type. `fstream` is no exception.

Comment: Then the solution should be single thread read, multiple thread consume, the typical consumer/producer model that you have to wrap around the istream.